# NancyFX: how to get posted form value?

Tags: c#, nancy

I am sending a form post into NancyFX via an Ajax post. In debug, I can see that the data is there. (`Request.Form.Keys.Count = 1` and `Value = 1`)

In debug I can see the key name, and the value.

When I try to access however using the notation indicated in documentation, I get null...

```
string Myvalue = Request.Form.MyData  // is null
var Myvalue = Request.Form["MyData"]  // is also null
```

Yet, I can see the name in `Request.Form.Keys` and the value in `Request.Form.Values`

I'm sure its something stupid - any ideas?

-- edit - here is ajax code --

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/ABC",
    **contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',**
    data: { FVSServer: $("#txtSomeValue").val()},
    async: false,
    success: function (results) {
    alert(results);
   }
  });
```

NB: strangely, even though its default, the contentType line above was required!  ... many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are posting with the correct `content-type` header. It needs to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or it is not form data in the world of HTTP